# HP Elitebook 6930p keyboard issue

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hp-elitebook

I am having a weird issue with this laptop.  The A, S, D and the 4 keys have stopped working on the keyboard.  Every other key, as far as I can tell, still works fine, but those 4 keys appear to be dead.  Has anyone else run across this and knows of a solution?  Those keys work fine when I've got an external keyboard attached either via USB or docking station, so I would assume it's somehow a hardware issue rather than software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes keyboard cable can get a little loose. Usually on HP laptops it is enough to unscrew three screws on the back and some tabs at front side and keyboard will pop out.

Once you pull keyboard out, you will notice small ZIF with flat cable that goes from motherboard to keyboard. Gently disconnect it (pop it open with small screwdriver) and connect it again.

There are more detailed instructions in [HP 6930p service manual](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01928566/c01928566.pdf).

If that does not help, there is high probability that physical damage happened to conductive traces and that you may need to replace whole keyboard (cca $50.00).

Comment: My attempts to reseat the cable failed to produce any effect, but I'm guessing the keyboard or cable has gone bad.  Guess it's off to support for a repair.

Comment: Never did circle back on this.  It was a broken keyboard and was replaced.